# Optimizing page for different resolutions

Tags: css, html

I am not a good techie, i want to optimize below page to different resolutions, i worked up to that much in a resolution of 1366 x 768 , I want to optimize this for 1024 x 768 and 800 x 600 resolution.

Your help is always appreciated

Thank you

Here is the html & Css of the page.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <title>Safari Island Resort </title>
        <!-- CSS : implied media="all" -->
        <!-- Our CSS stylesheet file -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css" />

        <!-- Including the Lobster font from Google's Font Directory -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/img/cordia.ttf" />

        <!-- Enabling HTML5 support for Internet Explorer -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>

    <body>

        <header></header>

    <nav>
            <ul class="fancyNav">
                <li id="news"><a href="#news">Eat & Drink</a></li>
                <li id="about"><a href="#about">Rooms</a></li>
                <li id="services"><a href="#services">Activities</a></li>
                <li id="contact"><a href="#contact">Spa</a></li>
                <li id="home"><a href="#home" class="homeIcon">Home</a></li>
                <li id="contact"><a href="#contact">Booking</a></li>
                <li id="contact"><a href="#contact">Home</a></li>
                <li id="contact"><a href="#contact">Boats</a></li>
                <li id="contact"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>

        </nav>
    </body>
</html>






 *{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

html{

    background:url('../img/bg.png')  no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;

}

body{
    font:14px/1.3 'Segoe UI',Arial, sans-serif;
    color:#888;
    padding:00px;
}


/*----------------------------
    CSS3 Animated Navigation
-----------------------------*/


.fancyNav{
    /* Affects the UL element */
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;

}

.fancyNav li{
    /* Specifying a fallback color and we define CSS3 gradients for the major browsers: */

    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top, left bottom,from(#fefefe), color-stop(0.5,#f0f0f0), color-stop(0.51, #e6e6e6));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#fefefe 0%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e6e6e6 51%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#fefefe 0%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e6e6e6 51%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#fefefe 0%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e6e6e6 51%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#fefefe 0%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e6e6e6 51%);

    border-right: 1px solid rgba(9, 9, 9, 0.125);

    /* Adding a 1px inset highlight for a more polished efect: */

    box-shadow: 1px -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) inset;

    position:relative;

    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}

.fancyNav li:after{

    /* This creates a pseudo element inslide each LI */    

    content:'.';
    text-indent:-9999px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:1;
    opacity:0;

    /* Gradients! */

    background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(168,168,168,0.5)),color-stop(0.5,rgba(168,168,168,0)), to(rgba(168,168,168,0.5)));
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(168,168,168,0.5), rgba(168,168,168,0) 50%, rgba(168,168,168,0.5));
    background-image:-o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(168,168,168,0.5), rgba(168,168,168,0) 50%, rgba(168,168,168,0.5));
    background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(168,168,168,0.5), rgba(168,168,168,0) 50%, rgba(168,168,168,0.5));
    background-image:linear-gradient(left, rgba(168,168,168,0.5), rgba(168,168,168,0) 50%, rgba(168,168,168,0.5));

    /* Creating borders with box-shadow. Useful, as they don't affect the size of the element. */

    box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 #fff,1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;
    -moz-box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 #fff,1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 #fff,1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;

    /* This will create a smooth transition for the opacity property */

    -moz-transition:0.25s all;
    -webkit-transition:0.25s all;
    -o-transition:0.25s all;
    transition:0.25s all;
}

/* Treating the first LI and li:after elements separately */

.fancyNav li:first-child{
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}

.fancyNav li:first-child:after,
.fancyNav li.selected:first-child:after{
    box-shadow:1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;
    -moz-box-shadow:1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;

    border-radius:4px 0 0 4px;
}

.fancyNav li:last-child{
    border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}

/* Treating the last LI and li:after elements separately */

.fancyNav li:last-child:after,
.fancyNav li.selected:last-child:after{
    box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 #fff;
    -moz-box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 #fff;

    border-radius:0 4px 4px 0;
}

.fancyNav li:hover:after,
.fancyNav li.selected:after,
.fancyNav li:target:after{
    /* This property triggers the CSS3 transition */
    opacity:1;
}

.fancyNav:hover li.selected:after,
.fancyNav:hover li:target:after{
    /* Hides the targeted li when we are hovering on the UL */
    opacity:0;
}

.fancyNav li.selected:hover:after,
.fancyNav li:target:hover:after{
    opacity:1 !important;
}

/* Styling the anchor elements */

.fancyNav li a{
    color: #5d5d5d;
    display: inline-block;
    font: 20px/4.1 Lobster, Arial, sans-serif;
    padding: 12px 28px 14px;
    position: relative;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    z-index: 2;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    white-space: nowrap;
    height: 80px;
    text-align: center;
}

.fancyNav a.homeIcon{
    background:url('../img/home.png') no-repeat center center;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 280px;
    height: 80px;
}


/*-------------------------
    Demo Page Styles
--------------------------*/


h1,h2{
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 1;
    background-color: #222;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI Light','Segoe UI',Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -446px;
}

h1{
    font-size: 36px;
    padding: 5px 15px 10px;
    top: 0;
}

h2{
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 4px 13px 9px 11px;
    top: 51px;
}

header{
    display:block;
    margin-top:50px;
    position:relative;
}

nav{
    display: block;
    margin:300 auto 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 1150px;
    position : absolute;
    bottom : 10px;
    width: 100%;

}

footer{
    color: #BBBBBB;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.6;
    padding: 10px 20px 0;
    text-align: center;
    display:block;
    position : absolute;
    bottom : 0px;

}

footer b{
    color: #888888;
    display: block;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: normal;
    position : absolute;
    bottom : 0;
}

a, a:visited {
    text-decoration:none;
    outline:none;
    color:#54a6de;
}

a:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some ways to do it.

First, you can use the icon as **background: url(your-image) no-repeat left center;** and set a **padding-left**.

Second, you can work with line-height or vertical-align it's a little more complex, but it works too.